# Ruby on Rails Guide: undefined method `fields_for' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am going working through the Rails Guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html),and am stuck at item 11 "Building a Multi Model Form".

This part of the excercise explains about including form fields for one model inside a form for another...

Error on New/Edit Post: **undefined method `fields_for' for nil:NilClass**

```
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <% @post.tags.build %>
2: <%= form.fields_for :tags do | tag_form | %>
3:   <div class="field">
4:     <%= tag_form.label :name, 'Tag: ' %>
5:     <%= tag_form.text_field :name %>
```

The code is exactly as per the excercise (I even got desperate and copy and pasted the code straight from the sample)

My code is posted below.. I have spent hours comparing this to the code in the guide, and it is exactly the same.. can anyone point me to what might be going wrong?

Many Thanks in advance.

Here is my code for including the partial

**models/post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :title, :tags_attributes

  validates :name, :presence =>true
  validates :title, :presence =>true,
                        :length => { :minimum => 5 }
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => :true,
    :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }
end
```

**models/tag.rb:**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

**posts/_form.html.erb:**

```
<% @post.tags.build %>
<%= form_for(@post) do |post_form| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= post_form.label :name %><br />
    <%= post_form.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= post_form.label :title %><br />
    <%= post_form.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= post_form.label :content %><br />
    <%= post_form.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <h2>Tags</h2>
  <%= render :partial => 'tags/form',
                     :locals => {:from => post_form} %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= post_form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**tags/_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form.fields_for :tags do | tag_form | %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= tag_form.label :name, 'Tag: ' %>
    <%= tag_form.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <% unless tag_form.object.nil?  || tag_form.object.new_record? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= tag_form.label :_destroy, 'Remove: ' %>
      <%= tag_form.check_box :_destroy %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: A typo here? `:locals => {:from => post_form}`

Comment: on searching google, one suggestion to use form_for instead of form.fields_for but that way the rendering was happening but no post back on post create or update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form is misspelled.

`:locals => {:from => post_form}`  to  `:locals => {:form => post_form}`

Answer (score 2):

Just a typo near the end of your post/_form

```
<%= render :partial => 'tags/form', :locals => {:from => post_form} %>
```

should be

```
<%= render :partial => 'tags/form', :locals => {:form => post_form} %>
```

form not from!!!